# Is the Application Delegate the right place to load a login view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm fairly new to Objective-C and trying to figure out best practices and the ways of doing things.

The app that I'm working on requires that the user login. Once logged in the login information is cached and they won't be asked ever again, unless they delete their user preferences.

The question I have is as login is mediatory, if login is required should I load the Login View Controller in the Application Delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method?

Currently the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of the App Delegate loads the tabBarViewController.

Should I put a condition here to load the Login View if login details are not stored, is this the right place to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is a fine place to put it, since you want it to happen at launch. You should consider making this a method that can be called from elsewhere, since I'm sure you'd want to let your users log out, then log back in subsequently.

Comment: I'm having issues trying to launch a modal view using `presentModalViewController` I get a message about incompatible types?

Comment: @Camsoft You should ask that as a new question, and be sure to include the broken code.